# KeyError: Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

need to update first dictionary with key in second dictionary. Got KeyError with Dictionary.

```
d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1}
dict3 = { k: [ d1[k], d2[k] ] if k in d2 else d2[k] for k in d1}
```

Expected Result

```
{'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3']}
```

Comment: Else cannot be satisfied given the condition: ``something if k in d2 else d2[k]`` evaluates ``d2[k]`` if k is *not* in d2. Did you mean ``else d1[k]``? If you always want a list, you need ``else [d1[k]]``.

Comment: You probably meant `else d1[k]`

Comment: use `collections.defaultdict(list)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ MisterMiyagi Thanks

```
d1 = {'product': '8', 'order': '8', 'tracking': '3'}
d2 = {'order': 1, 'product': 1}
dict3 = { k: [ d1[k], d2[k] ] if k in d2 else [d1[k]] for k in d1}

> {'product': ['8', 1], 'order': ['8', 1], 'tracking': ['3']}
```